# Update all rows in recyclerView simultaneously

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a list of countries and a double value about their currency. when I edit one of this currency I just want to update all other currencies on the list but I get this Error:

```
          java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call this method while RecyclerView is computing a layout or scrolling android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView{f4f8145 VFED..... .F....ID 0,32-736,1022 #7f070054 app:id/recyc}, adapter:app.ehsan.currencyapp.CurrencyAdapter@e9b409a, layout:android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager@6e59dcb, context:app.ehsan.currencyapp.MainActivity@7b7f00f
              at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.assertNotInLayoutOrScroll(RecyclerView.java:2663)
              at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$RecyclerViewDataObserver.onChanged(RecyclerView.java:5055)
              at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$AdapterDataObservable.notifyChanged(RecyclerView.java:11540)
              at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(RecyclerView.java:6762)
```

Because of this error, I used of Handler in my code like this:

```
G.handler.post(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        notifyDataSetChanged();
      }
    });
```

But with this change when I try to edit on a row app will not responsed any way(App will lock!).

This is my adapter code:

```
public class CurrencyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CurrencyAdapter.ViewHolder> {

  private Context mContext;
  private List<CurrencyModel> mList;
  private MainActivity activity;

  public CurrencyAdapter(Context mContext, List<CurrencyModel> mList) {

    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.mList = mList;
    this.activity = (MainActivity) mContext;
  }

  public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView txtName;
    ImageView imgIcon;
    EditText edtInput;

    public ViewHolder(View v) {
      super(v);

      txtName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txt_name);
      imgIcon = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.img_icon);
      edtInput = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.edt_input);
    }

  }


  @Override
  public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    // Create a new View
    final View v = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.list, parent, false);
    ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
    return vh;
  }

  @Override
  public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    holder.txtName.setText(mList.get(position).getName());


    switch (mList.get(position).getName()) {
      case "dollar":
        holder.imgIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.dollar);
        break;
      case "pound":
        holder.imgIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.pound);
        break;
      case "euro":
        holder.imgIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.euro);
        break;
    }

    holder.edtInput.setText("" + (int) mList.get(position).getValue());


    holder.edtInput.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
      @Override
      public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

      }

      @Override
      public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

      }

      @Override
      public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

        if (!holder.edtInput.getText().toString().isEmpty())
          convertor(position, holder);
      }
    });
  }

  private void convertor(int position, ViewHolder holder) {

    double value = 0;

    switch (mList.get(position).getName()) {

      case "dollar":
        value = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(holder.edtInput.getText())) * 3200;
        break;
      case "pound":
        value = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(holder.edtInput.getText())) * 4100;
        break;
      case "euro":
        value = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(holder.edtInput.getText())) * 3400;
        break;

    }

    for (int i = 0; i < mList.size(); i++) {

      if (position != i) {

        switch (mList.get(position).getName()) {

          case "dollar":
            mList.get(i).setValue(value / 3200);
            break;

          case "pound":
            mList.get(i).setValue(value / 4100);
            break;

          case "euro":
            mList.get(i).setValue(value / 3400);
            break;
        }
      }
    }

    G.handler.post(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        notifyDataSetChanged();
      }
    });
  }

  @Override
  public int getItemCount() {
    return mList.size();
  }
}
```

Comment: Instead of your adapter, call `notifyDataSetChanged()` in your activity or fragment.

Comment: @Heisen-Berg I tried that with a listener in my activity, But I got the same error!

Comment: Then you should use `notifyItemInserted()` instead of `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Comment: @Ehsan don't add addTextChangedListener on onBindViewHolder , everytime the list items get refreshed , you are setting a new listener to the list items

Comment: @ArashGM But I want to update rows when the user inserts a new value, And because of that I used ''addTextChangedListener ''